# How do I call a function in python?

Tags: python, function, encryption, vigenere

I am trying to call a new function called `def importFile():` however i am getting the error saying that `importFile()` isn't defined. What am i doing wrong, I know this is probably simple but I'm new to coding.

This is the section where I am trying to call the function:

```
 def main():
        myMode = input("Encrypt 'e' or Decrypt 'd': ")
        textFile = input("Would you like to import a text file 'Y' or 'N': ")
        if textFile == 'y' or textFile == 'Y':
            importFile()   
        myMessage = input('Enter your text: ')
        myKey = input('Enter your key: ')
        myKey2 = input('Enter your second key: ')
        if myMode == 'encrypt' or myMode == 'e':
            translated = encryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)
        elif myMode == 'decrypt' or myMode == 'd':
            translated = decryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)
        print('%sYour Message: ' % (myMode.title()))
        print(translated)
        print()
```

This is the Function:

```
def importFile():
    importText = []
    fileLocation = input('What is the name of the text file: ')
    open('fileLocation''r')
```

As you can probably tell i am trying to import text files in to python but haven't passed the first hurdle:)

Here is all the code:

```
LETTERS = 'ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'
def main():
    myMode = input("Encrypt 'e' or Decrypt 'd': ")
    textFile = input("Would you like to import a text file 'Y' or 'N': ")
    if textFile.lower() == 'y' :
        importFile()   
    myMessage = input('Enter your text: ')
    myKey = input('Enter your key: ')
    myKey2 = input('Enter your second key: ')
    if myMode == 'encrypt' or myMode == 'e':
        translated = encryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)
    elif myMode == 'decrypt' or myMode == 'd':
        translated = decryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)
    print('%sYour Message: ' % (myMode.title()))
    print(translated)
    print()

def encryptMessage(key, message):
    return translateMessage(key, message, 'encrypt')

def decryptMessage(key, message):
    return translateMessage(key, message, 'decrypt')

def translateMessage(key, message, mode):
    translated = []

    keyIndex = 0
    keys = key.upper()

    for symbol in message: 
        num =LETTERS .find(symbol.upper())
        if num != -1: 
            if mode == 'encrypt':
                num += LETTERS .find(key[keyIndex]) 
            elif mode == 'decrypt':
                num -= LETTERS .find(key[keyIndex])

            num %= len(LETTERS)

            if symbol.isupper():
                translated.append(LETTERS[num])
            elif symbol.islower():
                translated.append(LETTERS[num].lower())

            keyIndex += 1 
            if keyIndex == len(key):
                keyIndex = 0
        else:
            translated.append(symbol)
    return ''.join(translated)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

def importFile():
    importText = []
    fileLocation = input('What is the name of the text file: ')
    open('fileLocation','r')

main()
```

Comment: Is the function in the same `.py` file as main()?

Comment: The function must be defined before the main program hits that line of code.  If they're in the same file, you likely need to move the function definition *above* the main program.

Comment: Additionally, instead of using `textFile == 'y' or textfile == 'Y'`, it would be more Pythonic to say `textFile.lower() == 'y'`

Comment: There is no file at this time. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the advise aswell:)

Comment: @OwainWilliams What do you mean there is no file at this time?

Comment: You are already calling main before the importFile def. Move it to the end of the code. Btw., why are you calling main twice?

Comment: Im currently trying to add a feature to decrypt and encrypt text files so this code may be causing the problemb,`open('fileLocation','r')`. Just a theory.

Comment: @palsch You were correct. That fixed the code. Thanks mate:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

def importFile():
    importText = []
    fileLocation = input('What is the name of the text file: ')
    open('fileLocation','r')

main()
```

part.

At

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the `main()` function is called, but the `importFile()` isn't defined yet. Move it above the mentionned lines.

The additional `main()` at the end is not needed.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very helpful response.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you are calling main after defining importFile code? When inputting this code:

```
def main():
    myMode = input("Encrypt 'e' or Decrypt 'd': ")
    textFile = input("Would you like to import a text file 'Y' or 'N': ")
    if textFile == 'y' or textFile == 'Y':
        importFile()   
    myMessage = input('Enter your text: ')
    myKey = input('Enter your key: ')
    myKey2 = input('Enter your second key: ')
    if myMode == 'encrypt' or myMode == 'e':
        translated = encryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)
    elif myMode == 'decrypt' or myMode == 'd':
        translated = decryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)
    print('%sYour Message: ' % (myMode.title()))
    print(translated)
    print()

def importFile():
    importText = []
    fileLocation = input('What is the name of the text file: ')
    open('fileLocation','r')

main()
```

It should, and does, work perfectly fine on my machine.

Perhaps your importFile function is in a different file, in which case you should add `from ****file**** import importFile`.

One other thing I noticed is your final line, `open('fileLocation','r')`, needs a comma.

After looking at your edit:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

needs to be after `importFile` is defined.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\invent with python#####.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\invent with python#####.py", line 6, in main
    importFile()
NameError: name 'importFile' is not defined`

Comment: Without putting the whole contents of your file I can't do anything

Comment: updated the answer, importfile needs to be after if __name__ == '__main__': main()

Comment: In my code i called main twice so i needed to move the `importFile` above the other function. Thanks anyway youre answer was very good:)